# Java : reference one form from another form to append values

Tags: java, forms

In my application I have a main form which has buttons to process other actions, for example my main form displays a list of all entities in my system, and a user is then able to select and then Add or Edit those entities in the application.

When a user presses "Add" a new JFrame is opened, allowing them to add to the system.  This is all fine, however I am having a small problem which is affecting some functionality. 
I wrote a CommandTracker which allows me to undo and redo operations, the library works fine however I am struggling to reference the CommandTracker object on my main form from other forms. (hopefully code shall convey my question better)

Main Form Declarations:

```
protected CommandTracker;

// This is instantiated in my constructor, trying to show less code to keep simple.
objCommandTracker = new CommandTracker();
```

This instantiates my new Command Tracker object within my main form, I would then like to reference this object from my subform so that I can append the next command fired in my sub form.

So far I have tried to resolve this by providing a reference to my main form within my subforms .java file

```
protected static MainMenu main_menu = null;
```

I then tried to access the command tracker as follows

```
// Run AddRequestCommand, through the command tracker
mainMenu.objCommandTracker.executeCommand(addCommand);
```

However, this results in a null pointer Exception being thrown, I assume this is because mainMenu has a null reference in its declaration.  How do I go about passing the current active MainMenu instance to my subform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of statics is never the way to solve something like this. The solution is to pass valid references where needed and to call appropriate methods on these references.

So in other words, if one class needs reference to another, then pass the reference in via a parameter, either a constructor parameter or a setter method parameter, use it to set a field, and then you are free to call methods on that reference in that class.

---

As an aside: at some other time we'll need to discuss the problems with shooting multiple JFrames at the user, and at your atypical use of the term "form" as if it had a standard meaning in the Swing library -- it doesn't, and so you'll want to use other clearer terms.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply, sorry I'm tiered and have been staring at this problem for far too long; I got a little lazy on my terminology.   I feel extremely silly now realising that I can just pass my CommandTracker as a parameter to the JFrame when I open it, sorry to have wasted your time on such a simple problem - next time I shall revisit it in the morning instead of posting up on here before bed!

Comment: You were absolutely right, have this working by passing reference - thanks again.

Comment: I shall bare that in mind, may rework my app structure - thanks again, good night.